Impact of Anchor Position Errors on the Trilateration Problem
Trilateration Problem Setup
In trilateration, we start with three known points (anchors):

$P_1 = (x_1, y_1)$
$P_2 = (x_2, y_2)$
$P_3 = (x_3, y_3)$

Let the unknown position we want to determine be $((x, y)$, and the distances to these points be $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$. The distance equations can be expressed as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1. & \quad (x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 = d_1^2, \\
2. & \quad (x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2 = d_2^2, \\
3. & \quad (x - x_3)^2 + (y - y_3)^2 = d_3^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Linearization
By rearranging these equations and eliminating the quadratic terms, we can write:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 - d_1^2 = 0, \\
& (x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2 - d_2^2 = 0, \\
& (x - x_3)^2 + (y - y_3)^2 - d_3^2 = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Matrix Formulation
This system can be represented in matrix form. We define:

$A$ as the coefficient matrix,
$b$ as the constant vector.

The system can be expressed as:
$$
A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = b.
$$
Including Errors in $A$ and $b$
Now, let's introduce errors into the matrices. Let:

$A_{\text{true}}$ be the true coefficient matrix without errors.
$b_{\text{true}}$ be the true constant vector without errors.
$E_A$ be the error matrix added to $A$.
$E_b$ be the error vector added to $b$.

We can express $A$ and $b$ as:
$$
A = A_{\text{true}} + E_A,
$$
$$
b = b_{\text{true}} + E_b.
$$
Final Formulation
We express the position vector $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ in terms of the adjusted matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = A^{-1} b.
$$
Substituting the adjusted expressions for $A$ and $b$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = (A_{\text{true}} + E_A)^{-1} (b_{\text{true}} + E_b).
$$
Applying the Inverse
Using the first-order approximation for the inverse of a matrix, we express the inverse of the perturbed matrix as:
$$
(A_{\text{true}} + E_A)^{-1} \approx A_{\text{true}}^{-1} - A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_A A_{\text{true}}^{-1}.
$$
Substituting this into our equation gives:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \approx \left( A_{\text{true}}^{-1} - A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_A A_{\text{true}}^{-1} \right) (b_{\text{true}} + E_b).
$$
Distributing Terms
Distributing the terms, we have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \approx A_{\text{true}}^{-1} b_{\text{true}} + A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_b - A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_A A_{\text{true}}^{-1} b_{\text{true}} - A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_A A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_b.
$$
Simplified Result
For small errors, the dominant terms can be kept:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \approx A_{\text{true}}^{-1} b_{\text{true}} + A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_b - A_{\text{true}}^{-1} E_A A_{\text{true}}^{-1} b_{\text{true}}.
$$
Conclusion
The final expression can be summarized as:
$$
p \approx (A_{\text{true}} + E_A)^{-1} (b_{\text{true}} + E_b).
$$
At this point, I have considered the errors in both matrices $E_A$ and $E_b$ arising from the imperfect positions of the anchors. It is important to address the following questions:

Since $E_A$ and $E_B$ both stem from the error in the position of $P_i$, and given that I know the mean error and the variance of these errors, can we conclude that $\text{var}(E_A) = \text{var}(E_B) = \sigma I$?

If this assumption is valid, could someone assist me in calculating the covariance matrix?


